# Protobuf C++ message with google timestamp leads to seg fault

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I am new to using google protobuffers and I created a basic message:

```
message msg {  
    uint32 id = 1;                             
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 2;  
}
```

Now I created a small c++ program to use this [with the necessary headers]

```
int main(void) {
  auto m = msg{};
  m.set_id(2);
  auto timestamp = google::protobuf::Timestamp{};
  timestamp.set_seconds(time(NULL));
  timestamp.set_nanos(0);

  m.set_allocated_timestamp(&timestamp);

  std::cout << m.id() << std::endl;
  std::cout << m.timestamp().seconds() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, this program gives a seg fault.

```
free(): invalid pointer
[1]    9537 abort (core dumped)
```

where do I need to release memory?

Comment: Offtopic: `timestamp.set_seconds(time(NULL));` is also undefined behavior. No risk of crash, just you do not have a warranty that `time` returns seconds.

Comment: timestamp.set_seconds(time(NULL)); comes from the official protocol buffer site https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp but obviously I am open to better suggestions.

Comment: @MarekR for all intents and purposes, you do have this guarantee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A protobuf's `set_allocated_foo()` function will **take ownership** of the pointer and attempt to free it after message itself runs out of scope. See more at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated

Since your pointer points to the automatic object, attempt at deleting this pointer yields undefined behavior, in your case, a coredump.

To set protobuf's TimeStamp, you first have to obtain a pointer to it using `mutable_timestamp`, and than you can set it's individual fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no set_timestamp. I used set_allocated_timestamp as I could not find another set method to my surprise. So my actual question here is more: How do I set timestamp in a message

Comment: Then you have to `new` it instead of using an automatic object.

Comment: @Mike my bad. Timestamp is a message on it's own. Fixed the answer.

Comment: ...  auto timestamp = new google::protobuf::Timestamp{};
  timestamp->set_seconds(time(NULL));
  timestamp->set_nanos(0);
  e.set_allocated_timestamp(timestamp); ...
indeed fixes the problem.